# Cannot access <x:transform> results as variable

Tags: jsp, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using xlst in a jsp file to template an xsl source:

```
<x:transform xslt="${xslt}" doc="${xmlString}"></x:transform>
```

which works fine and displays the expected html on page.
However, I need to access this result as a variable for further use. I tried adding `var="printData"` as an attribute but

1. No formatting is done and no text appears in place of the `<x:transform>`
2. If I try to print out `${printData}`, `[#document: null]` is printed.

I've tried looking for documentation but I could find little to no information about the use of var, is it right? Is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Solved not with `var` on the transform, but by passing the data pre-transformation and transforming it via Java with

```
public static String elaborateXml(String xslPath, String xml) {
        try {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(
                    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xslPath));

            transformer.transform(
                    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader), 
                    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));

            String result = writer.toString();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```